# Mind the...(number seqeunce)

Tags: number-sequence

Find the next number in the sequence:

2, 3, 7, 23, 89, 113, ?

Hint:

> A corresponding sequence is ?, ?, 4, 6, 8, ?, ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> 523

A simple search in OEIS will render:

> [A002386](https://oeis.org/A002386)

Comment: But isn't OEIS like a cheat code (no offence, I'm new)? It feels like there's no point in this if you use OEIS. Anyway, did you figure out the rule?

Comment: no, we are supposed to check there first. in fact, usually we are not encouraged to post sequences from oeis since that would be of little meaning by simply asking others to search the oeis for the answer. see this post on meta to see what number sequence puzzles you should post: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do happy puzzling ;) +1 to your question :)